# post man api error please set x-api-key header correctly

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I'm new in laravel and make api
I have login form with only phonenumber
when test it on post man get this error

[image]

[image]

[image]

can please tell me how to solve it
thanks

Comment: Under the `headers` tab add one with `key` == `x-api-key` and `value` should be your API key?

Comment: in value should I write phone number?

Comment: No, you should add the API key that you got from the API provider.

Comment: But also, you are making a POST request and passing a GET parameter. So phone number should be under the `Params` tab as a key-value pair as well.